# Grails domainClasses get transient properties

Tags: grails, metaprogramming, grails-domain-class, transient

The class GrailsDomainClass has two methods: `getProperties` and `getPersistentProperties`

I have a domain class (`MyDomainClass`) which includes this:

```
static transients = {computeStuff}
float computeStuff(){
  def thisCouldChange = 3.1
  return thisCouldChange  //it actually does things but not of consequence to my question
}
```

Ok, I took the default index page and modified it to list all the properties of `MyDomainClass` as such:

```
<g:each var="d" in="${grailsApplication.domainClasses.sort { it.fullName } }">
<h2>${d.fullName}</h2>
<g:each var="f" in="${d.properties.sort { it.fieldName } }">
<br>${f.fieldName }
</g:each>
</g:each>
```

Ok.  That works, but it doesn't get any of the transient properties.  I have tried d.properties and d.persistantProperties and they seem to give me back the same results. Thanks in advance for your help!!

Do I need to call it getComputeStuff or something?

I have now changed my domain class to contain this and still do not get back the transient computeStuff

```
static transients = ['computeStuff']
float getComputeStuff(){
  def thisCouldChange = 3.1
  return thisCouldChange  //it actually does things but not of consequence to my question
}
```

This seems to have made no difference.

Comment: Have you tried defining computeStuff as a closure instead of a method, `float computeStuff = { ... }` ?  I'm not sure if that would affect it or not.

Comment: So `float computeStuff` pisses SessionFactory off, but `def computeStuff` gets me right back where I started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the static transient decleration. define your method as follows:

```
def getComputeStuff(){
  def thisCouldChange = 3.1
  return 3.1  //it actually does things but not of consequence to my question
}
```

after that a property call "computeStuff" should appear in your properties list calling getProperties() on the domain class. its very important that you define the return value as **def**.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want your `computeStuff` method be treated like a property, call it `getComputeStuff` - name convention as JavaBeans. I'm not sure id it will work, but it's worth a try I think ;)

Comment: Worth a try, but unsuccessful.  Thank you nevertheless for input.  See my new domain snippit above.